# Gravity problems with new api

Tags: android, methods, gravity

In the following code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    layoutDirection = getLayoutDirection();
    absoluteGravity = Gravity.getAbsoluteGravity(mGravity, layoutDirection);
}
```

I get this error::

> The method getAbsoluteGravity(int, int) is undefined for the type
>   Gravity

I am sure I am compiling with api number 16.
In the editor, when method windows appear, I can not see this methods.....

any idea how can I solve this

Answer (score 0):

According to the official Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLayoutDirection%28%29), the `View` method `getLayoutDirection()` is only available since API 17, not 16. Hence the warning you are getting.

About `getAbsoluteGravity()`, it is available since API 14, but it is static, meaning you have to call it directly from the `Gravity` class.

The method signature is the following:

```
public static int getAbsoluteGravity (int gravity, int layoutDirection)
```

Hope to have help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ViewCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#getLayoutDirection(android.view.View)) for getLayoutDirection()
and [GravityCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/GravityCompat.html#getAbsoluteGravity(int,%20int)) for getAbsoluteGravity() method